# repeated field in a subquery

Tags: arrays, subquery, google-bigquery

I'm trying to compare two string columns, one of them is in a repeated record and is located in the sub-query :

```
#standardSQL
SELECT name AS produit
FROM   samples.overmind_reports 
WHERE  name IN (SELECT lines.article.sub_category.label FROM   samples.orders_lines)
ORDER BY produit
```

Error:

> Cannot access field article on a value with type
>   ARRAY>, ...>> at [5:21]

Table schema:

[image]

I tried with `FLATTEN`, but it's a legacy function only ?

```
#standardSQL
SELECT name AS produit
FROM   samples.overmind_reports 
WHERE  name IN (SELECT lines.article.sub_category.label FROM (FLATTEN(samples.orders_lines,lines)))
ORDER BY produit
```

I got :

> Error: Syntax error: Expected keyword JOIN but got ")" at [6:50]

I fail to use `UNNEST`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  t1.name AS produit
FROM `samples.overmind_reports` t1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `samples.orders_lines` t2, UNNEST(t2.lines) lines WHERE lines.article.sub_category.label = t1.name)
ORDER BY 1
```

You can test with simulated data:

```
WITH `samples.overmind_reports` AS(
  SELECT 'name1' name UNION ALL
  SELECT 'name2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'name3'
),
`samples.orders_lines` AS(
  SELECT ARRAY<STRUCT<article STRUCT<sub_category STRUCT<label STRING> > > > [STRUCT(STRUCT(STRUCT('label' AS label) AS sub_category) AS article), STRUCT(STRUCT(STRUCT('name1' AS label) AS sub_category) AS article)] lines UNION ALL
  SELECT ARRAY<STRUCT<article STRUCT<sub_category STRUCT<label STRING> > > > [STRUCT(STRUCT(STRUCT('label' AS label) AS sub_category) AS article), STRUCT(STRUCT(STRUCT('name1' AS label) AS sub_category) AS article)] lines UNION ALL
  SELECT ARRAY<STRUCT<article STRUCT<sub_category STRUCT<label STRING> > > > [STRUCT(STRUCT(STRUCT('label' AS label) AS sub_category) AS article), STRUCT(STRUCT(STRUCT('name3' AS label) AS sub_category) AS article)] lines
)

SELECT
  t1.name AS produit
FROM `samples.overmind_reports` t1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `samples.orders_lines` t2, UNNEST(t2.lines) lines WHERE lines.article.sub_category.label = t1.name)
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Many thanks, the on line documentation don't relate this cross join  when the UNNEST operator is documented.

Comment: Did it work? As for the cross join, notice it's just a regular query being implemented, but used as a "sub-query".

Comment: It works, in a WHERE sub-query or in a WITH one. It looks like as the Oracle TABLE operator dealing with varray or nested tables.

Comment: cool :). If you think the answer helped you please consider accepting/up voting it as this is important in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers